# TikZ: Superimpose text over arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am trying to superimpose some text over an arrow with TikZ. I know it is possible to have the text *over* the arrow but this is not what I am trying to achieve.

What I have done so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node(n1){n1};
  \node(n2)[below right=3cm and 3cm of n1]{n2};
  \draw[->] (n1) -- node[sloped, fill=white]{Text} (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this only works on a white background. Is there a better way to do obtain the same result?

Comment: Your trick of `fill=white` helps me.

Answer (score 10):

One possibility would be to `draw` the text as a node. You can place it with a `path` help. Once all nodes are placed, `draw` the arrow(s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node(n1){n1};
  \node(n2)[below right=3cm and 3cm of n1]{n2};
  % this path will place/draw a node call (text)
  \path (n1) -- node[sloped] (text) {Text} (n2);
  % Now draw arrows. This way it will be like you want.
  \draw[->] (n1)--(text)--(n2);
  % If you use two draw commands, will get two arrows.
  %\draw[->] (n1)--(text);
  %\draw[->] (text)--(n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a neat solution to working out the position and orientation of the node (I'd just worked out a way to do it explicitly using the `calc` library but this is much better).  One minor change: you only need `(text)` once in the `\draw` command, I think.

Comment: @AndrewStacey You're right. I suppressed it according your suggestion.

Comment: Sadly, this won't work well (read: not at all) with other paths, curved or controlled.